# xgboost library not found on python

Tags: python, windows, git, xgboost

I tried to install xgboost on python thanks to the following instruction:

> I – Install MinGW Get the installer online :
>   https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
>   When installing, select 'Architecture' x86_64.
>   After the install procedure is completed, add the binaries path to your PATH 
>   environment variable: directory can be something like
>   C:\Users\username\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin
>
> How to: change PATH variable on windows:
>   https://www.java.com/fr/download/help/path.xml
>
> Help on errors: If you have another error in the install procedure,
>   get it from here
>   https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/threads-posix/seh
>
> Extract the file with 7zip in the directory of your choice (preferably
>   C:\Users\username\mingw64). Add the binaries path to your PATH 
>   environment variable: C:\Users\username\mingw64\bin
>
> II – Install Git https://git-scm.com/download/win  and run the
>   installer
>
> III – Install XGBoost on your computer open git bash shell in Windows,
>   and execute the following commands one by one:
>
> cd your_folder_for_xgboost https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
>
> cd xgboost git checkout 9a48a40 # This line is based on https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1267
>
> git submodule init
>
> git submodule update alias
>
> make='mingw32-make'
>
> cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
>
> make -j4
>
> IV – Install XGBoost on python In the anaconda command prompt:
>
> cd your_folder_for_xgboost/xgboost/python-package python setup.py install

All works well until the last command, there was an error that I don't understand how to resolve it. I tried to do it the second time but I still have the same error. I also tried to do the same thing on 2 different PCs and I had the same error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues and solutions:

1. The name of the MinGW64 installation folder shouldn`t have space. Therefore I do not recommend to install it by default in "Program Files".
2. You should restart your session (or even PC) after PATH editing.
3. Find mingw32-make.exe in MinGW64 folder and copy it again to this folder with renaming to make.exe. You can use *make='mingw32-make'* but I do not recommend it.

~Install GIT and XGBoost~

*git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost*

*cd xgboost*

*git submodule init*

*git submodule update*

*cp make/mingw64.mk ./config.mk*

4. Exec *make -j4*. If you can find xgboost.exe in XGBoost folder, then you did all right. If you get an error *unrecognized option '-pthread'*, open (for editing) file *Makefile* in XGBoost directory, find *-pthread* in it and add L letter before (*-lpthread*)

After that you can execute:

*cd python-package*

*python setup.py install*

Do not forget that your Python should have installed 'setuptools'. Or you can just install Anaconda package with all utils (I recommend this way).

Comment: The same error occurs or something has changed? Did you get xgboost.exe in XGBoost directory?

Comment: It was still the same error, and I didn't see the xgboost.exe file in the directory.

Comment: Ok, then try one more thing. Download Cygwin-x86_64: https://cygwin.com/install.html and use it instead of Windows command promt. Sometimes this help, sometimes not. In addition, you should check that the Git directory  added to PATH too

Comment: thank you very much, I will try it as soon as possible, but what do you mean by the Git directory? the directory where the Git Bash stocks?

Comment: Yes. You need something like    *C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Git\cmd;C:\DSLibs\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin*    in PATH variable.

Comment: thanks, I didn't have the xgboost.exe, this is the log after make -4, I suspect that the mingw64 doesn't work well for me. I didn't manage to install it from the official website so I choose the alternative: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQDrBqgn4AgdlpzOUJxY1ZFQ3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download  or https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/ or https://sf.net/p/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download

Comment: Have you tried using Cygwin? What did you get? Also your screenshot shows a common error when the folder name has a space. You can try to reinstall all the necessary tools in a separate directory. For example, I had put my programs to the DSLibs directory.

Comment: I uninstall all and re-install all of them, no space in the directory, but I still have the same error. It is very frustrating to install xgboost on python, it is much easier on R though. I think I will move to R.

Comment: Try to install(*python setup.py install*) it with my exec: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=80872674923673562480.  
If this wont help you, then I have not any other ideas, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to use the .exe file, I've checked the gcc version I have 5.1.0, is it too old for installing xgboost?

Comment: Just put it in the root of xgboost directory and execute 4 para: *cd python-package*  
and 
*python setup.py install*